# Traversing custom made list

Tags: c++, list, c++11, constants, nodes

I've been given a class declaration (create a list with nodes) in C++ that I need to define and I'm having trouble with one of the member functions: `void print() const;`

**Question:** How can I go about traversing and printing out the first->value's without removing `const` in the function declaration i.e. altering first? The function below yields an error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

Class declaration (only details of relevance)

```
class List {
public:
     .
     .
     .
    void print() const;
    int size();
    void add(int d);

private:
    int sz = 0;

struct Node {
        int value;  
        Node* next; 
        Node(int v, Node* n) : value(v), next(n) {}
};

    Node* first; // pointer to the first node
};
```

Class definition (only details of relevance)

```
void List::print() const {
    while (first != NULL) {
        cout << first->value << endl;
        first = first->next;
    }
}

int List::size() const {
    return sz;
}

void List::add(int d) {
    if (size == 0)
        first = new Node(d, NULL), sz++;
    else {
        Node* newnode = new Node(first->value, first->next);
        first = new Node(d, newnode);
        sz++;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Why do you think you have to modify `first` to traverse the list?

Comment: why do you want to change `first` in `print` function? if there is a reason for that, then why do you want it to be `const`?

Comment: I did try one function which worked if you call the function once (because it modified it) so when you'd call it once again it wouldn't print anything.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear: the reason it is const is because it was given to me like that and I believe there's a reason for it. I don't want to change first, it was the only way I knew how to "do it". The print() above yields an error saying: expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to make a copy of `first` and only modify the copy: (not tested)

```
Node* firstCopy = first;
while (firstCopy != NULL) {
    cout << firstCopy->value << endl;
    firstCopy = firstCopy->next;
}
```

Comment: I know it's advised not to but: Thanks. Unsure of why I didn't try this.

Comment: Do you understand what was wrong with your original version though?

Comment: @Useless If that's directed at OP, you should ping them with '@'

Comment: Doh, thanks. @crypt555 - it's worth making sure you understand the difference between data members (instance variables) and other variables.

Comment: @Useless Yes I believe I understand why It didn't work. I tried changing a data member inside a function declared `const`. Had that worked I'd only be able to use the `print()` once (once in regards to what output I wanted (the values in the list)). Is that correct?

Comment: Yep: you _can't_ do this because `const` stops you mutating the object, and you _shouldn't_ do this because the current iteration position of some function is not logically part of the object's own state.